# google-sheet : extract sub text from text

Tags: google-sheets

I have cells and each contains these text :

```
my_col_10x50_new
my_col_20x40_new
my_col_30x30_new
my_col_15x50_new
```

I want correspondingly to extract just the number parts and  make a "xx and xx" format like these :

```
10 and 50
20 and 40
30 and 30
15 and 50
```

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try a combination of substitute and regex extract:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "[0-9]+x[0-9]+"),"x", " and ")
```

The REGEXEXTRACT extracts the numbers along with the x in the middle and substitute replaces the x with the 'and' in the middle keeping the numbers as is.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\d+x\d+"), "x", " and ")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A,"x"," and "),"_"),0,3)
```

[image]